# Sending a custom error Through the API to appear in flutter

Tags: django, flutter, dart, django-rest-framework

I have a functioning flutter front to register users that consumes a Django-rest-framework API. With 3 fields (Username,Email and Password). I'm trying to add a snack-bar that shows up when the user fills a field incorrectly according to my validations. this is what i tried :

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Request was successful
      print('Signup successful!');
      // You can perform any other actions here, such as navigating to a new screen
    } else {
      // Request failed
      print('Failed to signup. Error: ${response.statusCode}');
       final Map<String, dynamic> errors = jsonDecode(response.body);
      String? key = errors.keys.first;
      String value = errors[key][0];
      print(value);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(
                            content:  Text('$value'),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                          ),
                        );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any exceptions that occur during the API call
    print('Error while signing up: $error');
    // You can display an error message to the user or perform other error handling actions
  }
}
```

For some reason when the password field or username field are Wrong i get a :
Failed to signup. Error: 500
Error while signing up: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1).
and when the email field is invalid i get the wrong error message (Enter a valid email address)  .
I'm still a beginner and am probably going about this the wrong way but the way i tried doing it was using the validations i passed with the API.
Here is the validation function:

```
def custom_validation(data):
    email = data['email'].strip()
    username = data['username'].strip()
    password = data['password'].strip()
    ##
    if not email or UserModel.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise ValidationError('choose another email')
    ##
    if not password or len(password) < 8:
        raise ValidationError('choose another password, min 8 characters')
    ##
    if not username:
        raise ValidationError('choose another username')
    return data
```

and here is the view :

```
class UserRegister(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request):
        clean_data = custom_validation(request.data)
        serializer = UserRegisterSerializer(data=clean_data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.create(clean_data)
            if user:
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(clean_data,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I planned on using clean_data as part of the API response to recover the ValidationError from.

Comment: What it says if you call the api with same data from Postman? What do you get on the log on the backend?

Comment: For the case where the email is incorrect i get a {
    "email": [
        "Enter a valid email address."
    ]
} in the other two cases i get a long HTML page